# Recreating strstr in C

Tags: c, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm trying to recreate `strstr` in c, my code works but I think it is too long, and it needs some improvement.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static int      find_str_indx(char *str, int index, char *str_to_find)
{
    int i;
    int temp;
    int found_index;

    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[index] == *str_to_find)
        {
            temp = index;
            i = 0;
            found_index = index;
            while (str_to_find[i] != '\0' && str[index] != '\0')
            {
                if(str_to_find[i] != str[index])
                    found_index = -1;
                i++;
                index++;
            }
            if (found_index == -1)
                index = temp;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return (found_index);
}

char    *my_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
{
    char    *found_str;
    int     found_index;
    int     i;

    found_str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(found_str));
    found_index = find_str_indx(str, 0, to_find);
    if (found_index != -1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while (str[found_index] != '\0')
        {
            found_str[i] = str[found_index];
            found_index++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
        found_str = NULL;
    return (found_str);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have rewritten the code to get rid of allocating memory inside `strstr`, as advised by `ratchet freak` and `Jerry Coffin`.

```
char    *my_strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    size_t  needle_len;

    needle_len = strlen(needle);
    while (*haystack)
    {
        if (*haystack == *needle)
        {
            if (!strncmp(haystack, needle, needle_len))
                    return ((char *)haystack);
        }
        haystack++;
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: fatal flaw in there, `sizeof(found_str)` is always the size of a pointer (4 or 8 depending on 32 or 64 bit) so it's very likely that you will overflow that buffer. Not to mention strstr shouldn't allocate anything in the first place. You also leak the `found_str` if you didn't find the substring.

Comment: Suggest `my_strstr()` document/test its intended/actual functionality with corner cases of `my_strstr("", "needle")`, `my_strstr("haystack", "")`, `my_strstr("", "")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This strikes me as somewhat...clumsy code that makes the job more difficult than truly necessary.

I'd break the task up into pieces, something like:

```
for every candidate position in the haystack
    if the needle matches at this point
        return success at this point
return failure
```

So that leaves us with two subordinate tasks:

1. Figure out the candidate positions
2. Check for a match starting at a specified point

The first is pretty simple: the candidate positions are the beginning of the haystack through the length of the haystack minus the length of the needle (and if the needle is larger than the haystack, it can't possibly match).

The second is even simpler: step through both strings, and if they don't match at a given point, return indicating failure. If (and only if) you reach the end of the second without a mismatch, return indicating success.

So let's write some code for that:

```
size_t length(char const *s) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++)
        ;
    return i;
}

bool match(char const *a, char const *b) {
    while (*b)
        if (*a++ != *b++)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then we can do the function itself:

```
char const *find_substr(char const *haystack, char const *needle) {
    size_t len1 = length(haystack);
    size_t len2 = length(needle);

    for (size_t i = 0; i+len2<=len1; i++)
        if (match(haystack + i, needle))
            return haystack + i;
    return NULL;
}
```

Then we probably want a bit of test code to verify that it works to at least some degree under some circumstances:

```
char const *check(char const *s) {
    if (s)
        return s;
    return "[NULL POINTER]";
}

#define elements(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

int main() {
    char input1[] = "This is some input for the function";

    // tests: match middle, non-match, match begin, match end, empty string
    char const *tests[] = { "for", "was", "This", "ion", "" };

    for (size_t = 0; i < elements(tests); i++)
        printf("%s\n", check(find_substr(input1, tests[i])));

    printf("%s\n", check(find_substr("the", "this is a longer string")));
}
```

There are certainly other ways the job could be done, but that seems to me like it's at least a reasonable way to implement what's probably the simplest (and most naive) one.

Comment: You might want  to make `i` `unsigned` or `size_t` instead of `int` within `main`.

Comment: @Edward: Good point (though I can't quite imagine having more than 32767 test cases to step through, so I'm pretty sure `int` remains adequate indefinitely).

Comment: `bool match(char const *a, char const *b)` has asymmetric functionality between `a,b` with `while (*b)`.  Maybe use `bool match(char const *haystack, char const *needle)`?

Comment: A good reason for using `size_t` over `int`, even with short list, it that it avoids the pedantic warnings of mixing signed/unsigned compare with `i < elements(tests)`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks, I have rewritten my code and followed your pseudo-code.

Answer (score 3):

Below are some of my rules.  Yours may differ.

- Embrace the pointer, and pointer auto-increment.  Indexes are ok, but so are pointers.
- Avoid the trap that all **if** statements must test a **boolean** value.  In C **if** statements can evaluate or test char, int, or even float.
- The test `if (*a == '\0')` is ok, but `if (*a)` is shorter.  Shorter is better.
- Dont feel guilty for putting a return in the middle of your code.  Not all subroutines must return or exit out of the bottom.
- Some prefer `while (1){ }`, but `for (;;){ }` is also pretty.  Maybe even prettier.
- It's not really an infinite loop if it has a `break` or `return` in it.
- Avoid using `break;` where `return;` would be better.
- Avoid nesting loops and if statements three or more deep.
- Small is simple.  Simple is correct. Go for correct first.  Then speed it up if you must.
- Once I write some code, I first ask myself, is it correct and can I make it smaller?

My favorite C implementation of strstr. It's not boyer-moore fast, but it is small.

```
   char * strstr (const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
      const char * a = haystack, *b = needle;
      for (;;) {
         if ( !*b ) return NULL;
         if ( !*a ) return haystack;
         if ( *a++ == *b++ ) continue;
         a = ++haystack;
         b = s2;
      }
    }
```

Comment: *"The test `if (*a == '\0')` is ok, but `if (*a)` is shorter. Shorter is better."*: Agree, but typo: should be `if (!*a)`

Comment: "Shorter is better." Go to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ and tell me if the C code you find there would get any good reviews on this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jerry Coffin on the overdone part. I recommend another algorithm however, which roughly is:

```
char* haystack;
char* needle;
int currentMatch = 0;
size_t hay_len = strlen(haystack);
size_t nee_len = strlen(needle);
for(int i = 0;i<hay_len;i++) {
    if(haystack[i] == needle[currentMatch]) {
        if(++currentMatch == nee_len) return i - currentMatch; // may or may not be off by one
    }else currentMatch = 0;
}
```

This is as optimized as I ever got for search for a pattern in another (ie a string in a string).